# Extract specific word cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a description field that contains multiple text. I want to extract a certain data that I need. Which is the "Group Code" and "Group Name". The text length of each cell might be different.

What formula can assist me to grab those two fields?

An example of what my description field look like and what I hope to extract from it on column "D" and "E":

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Regex is the cleanest way. Here's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) that'll get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard text parsing methods should be able to do this. The [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) and [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) can locate the static text labels as well as the `CHAR(10)` line feed that terminates the entry. The [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD) peels out the desrired subtext while [CLEAN](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/clean-function-328724f9-98cc-4a67-a50e-6bd8d33dcc61) and [TRIM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) tidy up the result. Finally, the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) substitutes a zero-length string instead of an error code (e.g. `#VALUE!`) if the text parsing is unsuccessful.

[image: Text Parsing]

The formula to get the **Group Code** in D2 is,

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(CLEAN(MID(B2, SEARCH("group code:", B2)+LEN("group code:"), FIND(CHAR(10), B2, SEARCH("group code:", B2))-(SEARCH("group code:", B2)+LEN("group code:"))))), "")
```

Fill down as necessary. Make the appropriate adjustments to the formula to retrieve the **Group Name** to E2.

Comment: I tried entering your formula in the field but it didn't work. Can you copy and paste it below. Maybe I entered something wrong. Thanks

Comment: Maybe your computer's regional system uses a semi-colon instead of a comma as a list separator in the system's regional settings. tbh, **'it didn't work'** isn't much to go on.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped You are awesome!